# JdbcDaoSupport with a SQL SELECT FROM INSERT

Tags: java, sql, jdbctemplate, spring-jdbc

I am trying to create a "select from insert" within my Spring JdbcDaoSupport class and am having trouble figuring out how to *get* the data from the select statement and return it.

My EventJdbcTemplate (my DaoImpl):

```
@Service
public class EventJdbcTemplate extends JdbcDaoSupport implements EventDao {

private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(EventJdbcTemplate.class);

private static final String SQL_INSERT_EVENT = "SELECT EVENT_ID FROM FINAL TABLE " +
        "(INSERT INTO EBT10DBB.SB0401T0 (EVENT_NAME, HOST_NAME, USER_ID) " +
        "VALUES(?, ?, \'EMP0321\'))";

@Autowired
public EventJdbcTemplate(DataSource pDataSource) {
    super.setDataSource(pDataSource);
}


@Override
public Integer createEvent(EventBean pEventBean) { //(Integer id, String eventName)
    if (LOGGER.isTraceEnabled()) {
        LOGGER.trace("Entering create(Event event) of EventJDBCTemplate.");
    }
    // This SQL works, but is for an INSERT only. 
    /*this.getJdbcTemplate().query(SQL_INSERT_EVENT, new Object[]{
        pEventBean.getEventName(),
        pEventBean.getHostName()
    });*/

    final List eventList = this.getJdbcTemplate().query(SQL_INSERT_EVENT, new Object[]{
        pEventBean.getEventName(),
        pEventBean.getHostName()
        }, new EventRowMapper()
    );

    Event event = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < eventList.size(); i++) {
        event = (Event)eventList.get(i);
    }

    if (LOGGER.isTraceEnabled()) {
        LOGGER.trace("Exiting create(Event event) of EventJDBCTemplate.");
    }
    //return statement -- should return either the entire "pEventBean", or
    //just the unique key, "EVENT_ID".
            return event.getId();
}
```

EventRowMapper class (Not sure is I'll need this for the select or not):

```
public class EventRowMapper implements RowMapper<Event> {

    @Override
    public Event mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        final EventBuilder event = new EventImpl.EventBuilder();
        event.setId(rs.getInt("EVENT_ID"));
        event.setEventName("EVENT_NAME");
        event.setHostName("HOST_NAME");
        return event.build();
    }

}
```

So my goal is to return an Integer value that would be the unique key (EVENT_ID) that is created from the INSERT SQL.

Comment: use  org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(String sql, Object[] args, RowMapper<Event> rowMapper) instead of queryForList and pass your EventRowMapper to it.

Comment: I updated the code a bit to use the RowMapper, but it still does not work completely. It is able to post the record to the database, but fails on the SQL: Invalid parameter: Unknown column name id. ERRORCODE=-4460, SQLSTATE=null;

Comment: Wow, got it to work finally. All I had to do was change event.setId(rs.getInt("id")); to event.setId(rs.getInt("EVENT_ID")); in the EventRowMapper class....ugh. EVENT_ID happens to be the actual name for the column in the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SimpleJdbcInsert provided by Spring to get back generated keys, see following documentation provided by Spring section

> 13.5.2 Retrieving auto-generated keys using SimpleJdbcInsert

Here is the [Link](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-simple-jdbc-insert-2)